# How to prevent onehalfspacing in a table?

Tags: longtable, tabularx, threeparttable, ctable

I have composed my document with *booktabs* as usually. Then I had to add some notes to one of the tables, so I have tried about every solution discussed on TSX out of which *ctabs* and *threeparttablex* seemed to be viable. Then I switched to prescribed 1,5 spacing.

Booktabs tables didn’t change, but both environments with notes support did.

How do I prevent this change in row spacing?

[image: different tabular environments with onehalfspacing set]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
  \KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
  \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
  \addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
  \addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}

\begin{document}

\ctable[caption=ctable]{lll}
{
    \tnote[†]{Groucho}
    \tnote[‡]{Harpo}
    \tnote[§]{Zeppo}
}
{                                                   \FL
    One\tmark[†]& Two           & Three             \ML
    foo         & bar\tmark[‡]  & baz               \NN
    alpha       & beta          & gamma\tmark[§]    \LL
}

\begin{table}
  \caption{booktabs}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
    One     & Two   & Three \\
  \midrule
    foo     & bar   & baz   \\
    alpha   & beta  & gamma \\
  \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}


\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \item[†] \label{tn:groucho} Groucho
        \item[‡] \label{tn:harpo} Harpo
        \item[§] \label{tn:zeppo} Zeppo
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{l l l}
        \caption{ThreePartTable}\\
        \toprule
            One\tnotex{tn:groucho}  & Two   & Three \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot
            foo     & bar\tnotex{tn:harpo}  & baz                       \\
            alpha   & beta                  & gamma\tnotex{tn:zeppo}    \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about  nesting a`singlespacing` environment in `table` (or the converse)? B.t.w., what did you do with Chico? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard silly me, that was easy! I will accept it as soon as you convert it to an answer. Chico is an unfortunate victim of M in my MWE ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply nest your tables in a `singlespacing` environment:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
  \KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
  \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
  \addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
  \addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]

\begin{singlespacing}
\ctable[caption=ctable, pos = htb]{lll}
{
    \tnote[†]{Groucho}
    \tnote[‡]{Harpo}
    \tnote[§]{Chico}
}
{ \FL
    One\tmark[†]& Two & Three \ML
    foo & bar\tmark[‡] & baz \NN
    alpha & beta & gamma\tmark[§] \LL
}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \caption{booktabs}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
    One & Two & Three \\
  \midrule
    foo & bar & baz \\
    alpha & beta & gamma \\
  \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}


\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \item[†] \label{tn:groucho} Groucho
        \item[‡] \label{tn:harpo} Harpo
        \item[§] \label{tn:chico} Chico
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{l l l}
        \caption{ThreePartTable}\\
        \toprule
            One\tnotex{tn:groucho} & Two & Three \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot
            foo & bar\tnotex{tn:harpo} & baz \\
            alpha & beta & gamma\tnotex{tn:chico} \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}
\end{singlespacing}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not `booktabs` that does something about the interline space, but rather it's `setspace` that fixes `table` and `figure` environments to use single spacing.

You can fix also `\ctable` and `ThreePartTable` to do it. Also, you need to save the meaning of `\tnote` as defined by `ctable`, because `threeparttablex` silently redefines it.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt]{scrreprt}
  \KOMAoption{captions}{tableheading}
  \usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
  \addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
  \addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{ctable}
% threeparttablex redefines \tnote
\LetLtxMacro{\ctabletnote}{\tnote}
%%%
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\setTableNoteFont{\footnotesize}

\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\ctable}
  {\begingroup\def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}\selectfont}
  {}{}
\xapptocmd{\ctable}
  {\endgroup}
  {}{}
\xpretocmd{\ThreePartTable}
  {\def\baselinestretch{\setspace@singlespace}\selectfont}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ctable[caption=ctable]{lll}
{
    \ctabletnote[†]{Groucho}
    \ctabletnote[‡]{Harpo}
    \ctabletnote[§]{Zeppo}
}
{                                                   \FL
    One\tmark[†]& Two           & Three             \ML
    foo         & bar\tmark[‡]  & baz               \NN
    alpha       & beta          & gamma\tmark[§]    \LL
}


\begin{table}
  \caption{booktabs}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
  \toprule
    One     & Two   & Three \\
  \midrule
    foo     & bar   & baz   \\
    alpha   & beta  & gamma \\
  \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}


\begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
        \item[†] \label{tn:groucho} Groucho
        \item[‡] \label{tn:harpo} Harpo
        \item[§] \label{tn:zeppo} Zeppo
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{l l l}
        \caption{ThreePartTable}\\
        \toprule
            One\tnotex{tn:groucho}  & Two   & Three \\
        \midrule
        \endhead
        \endfoot
        \bottomrule
        \insertTableNotes
        \endlastfoot
            foo     & bar\tnotex{tn:harpo}  & baz                       \\
            alpha   & beta                  & gamma\tnotex{tn:zeppo}    \\
    \end{longtable}
\end{ThreePartTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd avoid `ctable`, anyway.

Comment: Wow, this is like watching M. Poirot clarifying that alleged victim is actually a devious murderer! There’s something else going on behind the curtains – without _threeparttablex_ included _ctable_'s notes are not typeset online but like in Table 0.3. Also, I cannot help myself but ask: Why would you avoid _ctable_? (given it’s the most recent of discussed packages)

Comment: @Mr.Tao I see no advantage at all in `ctable`. And, as you saw, it conflicts with `threeparttablex`, because they both define `\tnote` (in different ways).

Comment: @Mr.Tao I fixed the output by saving the meaning of `ctable`'s `\tnote` as `\ctabletnote`.